# How to correctly insert all the enum values into an hashset?

Tags: java, collections, enums, enumeration

I have the following problem in Java.

I have this eunm that contains 2 values that represent 2 String values **"COORDINATION"** and **"PISC"** :

```
private enum exclusion {COORDINATION, PISC};
```

So I have create this **getEnums()** method that return an **HashSet** containing the values of the enum as a String:

```
private static HashSet<String> getEnums() {

    HashSet<String> values = new HashSet<String>();

    for (Exclusion e : Exclusion.values()) {
        //values.add(Exclusion.values());
        values.add(Exclusion.values().toString());
        System.out.println("Inserted values: " + e.values().toString());
    }

    return values;
}
```

The problem is that when this method is called the returned **values** object contains 2 String as I espect but using the deubugget the values putted into this **HashSet** are not **"COORDINATION"** and **"PISC"** but something like this:

```
Inserted values: [Legp.prc.km.actions.configurationProject.ConfigurationProjectAction$Exclusion;@34653605
Valore inserito: [Legp.prc.km.actions.configurationProject.ConfigurationProjectAction$Exclusion;@39510a30
```

I think that the problem is related about how I insert the values into the values HashSet

Then, elsewhere into my code, I have the following cycle:

```
HashSet esclusionHashSet = getEnums();
for (DLFolder dlFolder : listFolder) {
    if (dlFolder.getPath().split("/").length <= 4 && dlFolder.getPath().contains(KmConstants.TAXONOMY_PARENT_FOLDER) && !esclusionHashSet.contains(dlFolder.getName())) {
        treePath.put(dlFolder.getPath(), dlFolder);
        path.add(dlFolder.getPath());            
    }
}
```

As you can see in this for all element into an object of my list I check if the name of the **dlFolder** object (that could be **"COORDINATION"** or **"PISC"** is not into the **esclusionHashSet** that contains the values inside my original **exclusion** enum, the check is done by:

```
!esclusionHashSet.contains(dlFolder.getName())
```

The problem is that it returns alwaysl FALSE (it seems that the **esclusionHashSet* does not contain the **"COORDINATION"** and **"PISC"** values)

How can I fix this issue? What am I missing?

Comment: Add a `toString()` to your enum class, otherwise you'll get the default one - as you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
for (Exclusion e : Exclusion.values()) {
    //values.add(Exclusion.values());
    values.add(Exclusion.values().toString());
    System.out.println("Inserted values: " + e.values().toString());
}
```

You should do:

```
for (Exclusion e : Exclusion.values()) {
    values.add(e.name());
    System.out.println("Inserted value: " + e.name());
}
```

What you are currently adding is the String representation of the array containing all the values of your enum, not the String representation of every value.